# About WPF RichTextBox with Spellchecker enabled

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"

...property in a wpf application, it works in machines with S.O Windows XP and with Office 2007, but whats the matter with Pc with Office 2003? it seems the spellchecker is disabled, this issue can be fixed with code? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure both machines are in the same (or a supported locale), because an interesting problem with the SpellCheck object is it only works in the following locales:

- English
- French
- German
- Spanish

You can also try this block of code from Microsoft:

```
textBox1.Language =
    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```